# DATEDIFF() function

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have to find the difference in two dates (dates have to converted from string to date format). I am using the following mysql query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF
(
        (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(create_date, '%e %b %Y  %k:%i') AS create_date FROM booking) AS date1
        ,
        (SELECT STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%e %b %Y  %k:%i') AS start_date FROM booking) AS date2
) diff
```

Individually the inner queries work successfully. 
The date format is correctly converted for example from `5 Mar 1985 2:33` to `1985-03-05 02:33:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is stopping you from

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF( 
    STR_TO_DATE(create_date, '%e %b %Y  %k:%i'),
    STR_TO_DATE(start_date, '%e %b %Y  %k:%i')
  ) AS diff
FROM booking
```

Comment: Thanks 
I must be aware of this. And now I wont be stopped. THanks